# Issue with factory girl association and use of let:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have a strange issue. I created a factory user_deals  for a user/deal has_many/has_many relationship but it seems like rspec is forcing me now to assert a user even if I don't need one (indeed users are only logged içn my database and needed in the app if a web visitor logs in)

This test is NOT working:

```
context "As NON SIGNED-IN visitor" do       

    describe "HP card has the right content and behavior on small screens (1-column view)", :js => true do      

      let(:subject) { ApplicationController.new } 
      let(:deal_for_german_people)  { create(:deal_skips_validate,   
                                                :country          => "Germany",
                                                :title            => "title of deal for German people") }   
let(:deal_for_german_people2)  { create(:deal_skips_validate,   
                                                :country          => "Germany",
                                                :title            => "title 2 of deal for German people") }  

      before do
        resize_window_to_mobile            
      end  

      after do
        resize_window_default
        end

      it "plus and minus icons behave correctly" do
        visit root_path
        # user sees on mobile the little "plus" icon by default
        expect(page).to have_css('.card-detail-opener', visible: true)  
    end

end
```

**But if I add create(:user) and I create "user_deals", the test passes.** But I'm in the context "non signed in user", so why should I create a user and user_deals ?

```
context "As NON SIGNED-IN visitor" do       

    describe "HP card has the right content and behavior on small screens (1-column view)", :js => true do      

      let(:subject) { ApplicationController.new }
      let(:user)                    { create(:user,
                                                user_country_name: 'Germany')  }  
      let(:deal_for_german_people)  { create(:deal_skips_validate,   
                                                :country          => "Germany",
                                                :title            => "title of deal for German people") }   
let(:deal_for_german_people2)  { create(:deal_skips_validate,   
                                                :country          => "Germany",
                                                :title            => "title 2 of deal for German people") }  

      before do
        resize_window_to_mobile
        create(:user_deal, user: user, deal: deal_for_german_people)
        create(:user_deal, user: user, deal: deal_for_german_people2)
      end  

      after do
        resize_window_default
        end

      it "plus and minus icons behave correctly" do
        visit root_path
        # user sees on mobile the little "plus" icon by default
        expect(page).to have_css('.card-detail-opener', visible: true)  
    end

end
```

Also, still investigating the reason of this weirdness, I found out that if I don't use the "let:" at the beginning of the test, but instead create variables @deals inside th before ...do block, it works without creating a user (but I would like to use rspec "let" to DRY and apply [rspec best practices](http://betterspecs.org/#let))

```
describe "HP card has the right content and behavior on small screens (1-column view)", :js => true do      


    let(:subject) { ApplicationController.new }     

      before do
        resize_window_to_mobile

        @deal_for_german_people = FactoryGirl.build( :deal,

                                                      :country          => "Germany",
                                                      :title            => "title of deal for German people").save(validate: false) 
@deal_for_german_people2 = FactoryGirl.build( :deal,

                                                      :country          => "Germany",
                                                      :title            => "title 2 of deal for German people").save(validate: false) 
      end  

      after do
        resize_window_default
        end

      it "plus and minus icons behave correctly" do  
        visit root_path
        expect(page).to have_css('.card-detail-opener', visible: true)
      end
```

**Models**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :user_deals,           dependent:  :destroy
  has_many   :users,                through:    :user_deals
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_deals          
  has_many :deals,                through: :user_deals
end

class UserDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user,         :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  belongs_to :deal,         :foreign_key => 'deal_id'
end
```

Structure of table user_deals

```
# Table name: user_deals
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id            :integer
#  deal_id            :integer
#  number_of_clicks   :integer          default(0)
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
```

Factory user

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }

    password "vddfdf"
    password_confirmation "vddfdf"

    confirmed_at Time.now
    confirmation_token nil

    trait :superadmin do
      role :superadmin
    end

    trait :with_deals do 
      after(:create) do |user|
        create_list(:deal, 5, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Factory user_deal

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_deal do
    association :user
    association :deal

    trait :few_clicks do
      number_of_clicks 1
    end

    trait :many_clicks do
      number_of_clicks 4
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what was the error shown in rspec in your "This test is NOT working:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are expecting both

```
let(:deal_for_german_people) ...
let(:deal_for_german_people2) ...
```

to be created before the `it` block. However, in your first failing scenario, this is not the case because you didn't call/use these variables in any part of the `it` block. You should treat `let` variables as if they are code waiting to be run.

I think what you want is `let!` which is ran immediately.

The following might then work

```
context "As NON SIGNED-IN visitor" do       
  describe "HP card has the right content and behavior on small screens (1-column view)", :js => true do      
    ...
    let!(:deal_for_german_people)  { create(:deal_skips_validate,   
                                                :country          => "Germany",
                                                :title            => "title of deal for German people") }   
    let!(:deal_for_german_people2)  { create(:deal_skips_validate,   
                                                :country          => "Germany",
                                                :title            => "title 2 of deal for German people") }  
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks. I ll provide the error output and test this tomorrow